# IE8 icon like checkboxes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-8

I have made icon like checkboxes that on click changes the color of the icon. It seem to work on Chrome, IE9+. But i need to make them work on IE8 (on click icon is not being changed).

**HTML**

```
<input id="checkbox1" class="icon-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox1">
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash unchecked'></span>
<span style='color:red;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash checked'></span>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type='checkbox'].icon-checkbox{display:none}
input[type='checkbox'].icon-checkbox+label .unchecked{display:inline}
input[type='checkbox'].icon-checkbox+label .checked{display:none}
input[type='checkbox']:checked.icon-checkbox{display:none}
input[type='checkbox']:checked.icon-checkbox+label .unchecked{display:none}
input[type='checkbox']:checked.icon-checkbox+label .checked{display:inline}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tadasvu/DTcHh/14579/

P.S i have: html5shiv.min.js,respond.min.js included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the sibling selector if you want legacy IE compatibility, call the classes directly. That should fix it.